# Select para um período em especifico no MySQL

Tags: mysql, query

Eu sei que se eu quiser consultar a data de 5 dias atras, eu uso a seguinte Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE Data = DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

Ou quiser voltar dois meses atrás eu substituo o `DAY` por `MONTH`:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE Data = DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 2 MONTH);
```

Porém, como faço pra voltar 2 meses e 5 dias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é fazer 2 operações:

```
WHERE Data = DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 MONTH), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Outra:

```
WHERE Data = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL - 2 MONTH + INTERVAL - 5 DAY;
```

> Veja ambas funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b13c7/1)**.

Comment: Era isso msm, muito obrigado